# Update ACF field based on user's email domain

Tags: wordpress, hook, advanced-custom-fields

I need some help and I can't seem to figure it out since I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

I have a custom post type called Companies. In the admin user interface, I have created an ACF relationship field to the Companies post type called `user_company`. Right now I am manually selecting the Companies post based on the user's email address and I would like to do this programatically.

```
`
```

```
function update_user_company( $user_id, $args ) {
  $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
    $email = $user->user_email;
    $company = get_field('user_company');

    list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $args['user_email'] );
    if ($domain == 'gmail.com') {
        $company[] = 'Google';
        update_field('user_company', $company, $post_title);
    };
    if ($domain == 'amyling.com') {
        $company[] = 'Pearlsin Arts';
        update_field('user_company', $company, $post_title);
    };
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'update_user_company', 10, 2 );
```

```
`
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, when you create a new user and add its email you want the right company to be automatically choose in the ACF user_company field right?

Comment: @C0G1T0 yes, that is correct.

Comment: you haven't declared $post_title in function what it is?

Answer (score 1):

I think your function is correct and the only thing that seems wrong is that you try to update a custom field based on a post title and you should use the post ID or in your case the user ID instead.

So you should try this:

```
function update_user_company( $user_id, $args ) {
  $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
    $email = $user->user_email;
    $company = get_field('user_company');

    list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $args['user_email'] );
    if ($domain == 'gmail.com') {
        $company[] = 'Google';
        update_field('user_company', $company, $user_id);
    };
    if ($domain == 'amyling.com') {
        $company[] = 'Pearlsin Arts';
        update_field('user_company', $company, $user_id);
    };
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'update_user_company', 10, 2 );
```

Hope this helps